# Deserialising object on Android causes arraylists to be empty

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist

I have a problem with serialisation on Android.
Server is written in Java. It serialises DataContainer object with ArrayList of Objects. In this case Menu object containing an ArrayList of Category objects and sends it to Android device. When I deserialise it, it works, but ArrayList categories size is 0. When I use a client written in normal Java it works perfectly.
Every Class implements Serializable, Server and Android app are using the same package (also serialising and deserialising of another objects works fine). Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Here are the code fragments:

Menu:

```
public class Menu implements Serializable { 
    public ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
}
```

Category:

```
public class Category implements Serializable {
    Integer category_id;
    String name;
   public ArrayList<Product> products;  
}
```

And so on in Product class (i removed setters and getters).

Deserialisation code:

```
 o = server.readObject();
 dc = (DataContainer) o;
 while(!dc.data.isEmpty()) {

           o = dc.data.remove(0);           
           if(o instanceof Menu) {
           if(mds.saveMenu((Menu) o))
           m = (Menu) o;
           Log.i("Synchronizacja", "Zapisano menu " + m.getCategories().size()); // This line says that categories.size() is 0
  }
```

Desktop Java deserialisation code:

```
public void manageInput(Object o){
    DataContainer dc = (DataContainer) o;
    Menu m = (Menu) dc.data.get(0);
    System.out.println(m.categories.size()); // This line returns a non-zero value
}
```

Comment: I do not know but maybe this can help. Try to change your declaration from ArrayList to simply List: 'public List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();'

Comment: Thanks for your response, but sadly it still doesn't work.